# How to run multiple commands ssh bash script

Tags: ssh

I want to run multiple commands in a Bash script in ssh with this commands and i would like to execute each command after finish each.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just move the bash script to the destination and invoke the script there.

Answer (score 3):

As NickW has said, you can use double-ampersands to separate commands into a single line.

However, you should also understand what the double-ampersand does and decide if you need to use it or just a semi-colon.

Double-ampersands will execute the next command **only if** the preceding command exits with a status of zero. In the below example, `command3` will not be run if `command1` or `command2` fails.

`ssh user@host "command1 && command2 && command3"`

Semi-colons will execute all commands regardless of exit status. In the below example, all three commands will be run.

`ssh user@host "command1;command2;command3"`

In short: double-ampersands should be used if the commands depend on each other, semi-colons should be used if they don't.

With this specific example, however, you should consider moving/deploying the script to the target server and invoking it over SSH, as combining all of those commands will result is a large and unwieldily SSH command.

`ssh user@host "/path/to/script.sh"`

Comment: A very valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to separate the commands with two ampersands `&&`.

So you would write this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute && /usr/bin/php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Using the `&&` to append the next command.

Comment: Normally im was using SLEEP command between 2 or more commands, but i would like to let the command to finish the job and on finish it go to the second, third, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

&& is the right way to do it, however, if you have a lot of tasks, visually it is confusing.
A more elegant solution is something along the following lines:

```
$phppath = /usr/bin/php

array = (catalog_product_attribute, ...)

for item in ${array[*]}
    $phppath indexer.php --reindex $item`
```

NOTE: The code is untested, but is conceptually correct.

Comment: I find the above posted way to be less confusing despite many lines... But then that is opinion and the above code seems to be kind of `psuedo code`... doesn't appear to be valid `bash` at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes to send the contents of a script to a remote system.

Try something like this: `cat file | ssh remote bash`